# Modern UI (WPF): Trying to use MUI for a WPF control in class library

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to use MUI framework for a existing WPF control (the WPF control is in class library). I've looked the MUI example for a modern window and tried to copy the resourceDictionary I found in the App.xaml.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml"/>                 
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>           
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

The issue that at design time, the UI seems to be have changed (look at the data)
[image]

but during running time, I'm getting exception (xamlparse exeption) that has an inner exception saying it was unable to locate the file or assembly FirstFloor.ModernUI.

I've used nuget to include the MUI framework the dll's copy to local is true.

I've also tried

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" /> 
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml"/>
```

and it doesn't work.

Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pack://application:` apparently scope to the calling application. In my case the compiled dll was called from an exectuable (3rd party vendor SOLIDWORKS). I had to copy paste the FirstFloor.ModernUI dll in the folder of the SOLIDWORKS executable that solves the problem.

If anyone can provide a better answer (that doesn't involve this manually intervention), I'll tick their answer.

Comment: Of course the executable application needs to be shipped along with the assembly in which the resources are defined.